# Ubuntu 19;10 server install on Raspberry PI 4 hangs on cloud init

Tags: server, raspberrypi, 19.10

I am trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 on a raspberry PI 4
Every time I do try it hangs on"cloud init"
I have left the machine on over night but it just sits.
I apologize in advance as I am a raspberry PI newbie but have installed Ubuntu on PCs but just can't seem to get past this

Comment: Did you verify ISO download?  Assuming you did; I'd write it to memory-card again (or try a different memory card)

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install? The supported images are "pre-installed" which means they're just flashed to an SD card. There is currently a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/+bug/1543459) where, on first boot, the login prompt appears before cloud-init has finished creating the first user, but if you wait for cloud-init to announce it's finished you should then be able to login (usually takes a couple of minutes, certainly not more than 5). On subsequent boots, there's no need to wait.

Comment: I downloaded it straight from ubuntu as an image which I flashed to a micros sd  card. I did see a previous post which mentioned  adding total_mem=2048 to the usercfg.txt file That seemed to help get me through the install but then I guuess there is no less memory available

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need/want cloud-init, one way to bypass it hanging is to purge it altogether. My install was hanging as well on the second+ boot (Raspberry Pi 4 4GB), and all I had done to the base install on the first boot ([19.10 Server 32bit armhf](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)) was run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`...but I knew the IP address of the machine, so I tried an [ssh](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2019/10/17/enable-secure-shell-ssh-service-ubuntu-19-10/) connection from my other computer...and it worked!

Once you're logged in via your SSH connection, follow [these instructions](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2019/04/19/remove-cloud-init-from-ubuntu/) to purge cloud-init.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a first successful boot

`sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled`

And that's it. Then you can decide whether you want to

`sudo apt purge cloudinit`

or you are fine with your Rasperry's boot